# Wireless Debian don't up

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, realtek

I'm using Debian 8.5 in my notebook, but the wifi doesn't work.
I've formatted it four times and the same error happen.

I've installed a realtek-firmware and but not resolve this.
This is the result from lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1904 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1916 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d60 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d61 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d14 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d48 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1346 (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 003e (rev 32)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

I've install the firmware-atheros and firmware-linux-free , nothing resolve..
I've install linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64

```
uname -r
3.16.0-4-amd64



iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.



ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether f4:8e:38:e4:52:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.189.104/24 brd 192.168.189.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 6843sec preferred_lft 6843sec
inet6 fe80::f68e:38ff:fee4:5243/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 32)
   Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0310]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

My Sources.list

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.5.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160604-15:35]/ jessie contrib main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.5.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160604-15:35]/ jessie contrib main

deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free


deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

#### EDIT

GAD3R

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-atheros
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-atheros is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 124 not upgraded.

modprobe ath10k
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath10k not found.
```

When I run make defconfig-ath10k

```
WARNING: "ath10k_thermal_event_temperature" [/home/rod/backports-20160324/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ath10k_thermal_set_throttling" [/home/rod/backports-20160324/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ath10k_thermal_register" [/home/rod/backports-20160324/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ath10k_thermal_unregister" [/home/rod/backports-20160324/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko] undefined!
```

result:

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174# ls
hw2.1  hw3.0

modprobe ath10k
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath10k not found.
```

#### EDIT

lsmod command

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
i915                  837235  0 
bnep                   17431  2 
nfsd                  267128  2 
auth_rpcgss            51211  1 nfsd
oid_registry           12419  1 auth_rpcgss
nfs_acl                12511  1 nfsd
nfs                   188136  0 
lockd                  83389  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                45542  1 nfs
sunrpc                237402  6 nfs,nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         25280  0 
mmc_core              102374  1 rtsx_usb_sdmmc
rtsx_usb_ms            16899  0 
memstick               13696  1 rtsx_usb_ms
rtsx_usb               17541  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
mfd_core               12601  1 rtsx_usb
nls_utf8               12456  1 
nls_cp437              16553  1 
vfat                   17135  1 
fat                    61986  1 vfat
ecb                    12737  1 
uvcvideo               79005  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12816  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       12519  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         47787  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            12995  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              126451  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  18305  2 uvcvideo,videodev
btusb                  29721  0 
bluetooth             374429  21 bnep,btusb
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
ath10k_pci             36849  0 
ath10k_core           253320  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    26067  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              555131  1 ath10k_core
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    12951  0 
coretemp               12820  0 
kvm_intel             139116  0 
kvm                   388784  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45118  1 
crc32_pclmul           12915  0 
cfg80211              432934  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
snd_hda_codec_realtek    67168  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    63181  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
aesni_intel           151423  1 
nouveau              1122508  0 
aes_x86_64             16719  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    12757  1 aesni_intel
dell_laptop            17077  0 
mxm_wmi                12515  1 nouveau
gf128mul               12970  1 lrw
dcdbas                 13313  1 dell_laptop
snd_hda_intel          26407  4 
dell_wmi               12477  0 
sparse_keymap          12818  1 dell_wmi
ttm                    77862  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         49210  2 i915,nouveau
drm                   249998  4 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
joydev                 17063  0 
evdev                  17445  23 
i2c_algo_bit           12751  2 i915,nouveau
compat                 18344  3 cfg80211,mac80211,ath10k_pci
rfkill                 18867  4 cfg80211,bluetooth,dell_laptop
glue_helper            12695  1 aesni_intel
tpm_tis                17231  0 
pcspkr                 12595  0 
efi_pstore             12805  1 
ablk_helper            12572  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 14516  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
serio_raw              12849  0 
battery                13356  0 
tpm                    31511  1 tpm_tis
efivars                17257  1 efi_pstore
snd_hda_controller     26646  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         104500  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
fuse                   83350  1 
snd_hwdep              13148  1 snd_hda_codec
wmi                    17339  3 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
ac                     12715  0 
button                 12944  2 i915,nouveau
video                  18096  2 i915,nouveau
acpi_cpufreq           17218  0 
acpi_pad               21165  0 
processor              28221  5 acpi_cpufreq
snd_pcm                88662  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65244  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
soundcore              13026  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
parport_pc             26300  0 
shpchp                 31121  0 
ppdev                  16782  0 
lp                     17074  0 
parport                35749  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                35529  2 
hid_generic            12393  0 
usbhid                 44460  0 
ext4                  473801  3 
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                17171  1 ext4
jbd2                   82514  1 ext4
dm_mod                 89405  9 
sg                     29973  0 
sd_mod                 44356  4 
crc_t10dif             12431  1 sd_mod
crct10dif_generic      12581  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       13387  1 
crct10dif_common       12356  3 crct10dif_pclmul,crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif
crc32c_intel           21809  0 
psmouse                99249  0 
ahci                   33334  3 
libahci                27158  1 ahci
libata                177508  2 ahci,libahci
xhci_hcd              152977  0 
r8169                  68262  0 
mii                    12675  1 r8169
scsi_mod              191405  3 sg,libata,sd_mod
usbcore               195468  5 btusb,uvcvideo,rtsx_usb,usbhid,xhci_hcd
i2c_hid                17410  0 
usb_common             12440  1 usbcore
thermal                17559  0 
fan                    12681  0 
thermal_sys            27642  5 fan,video,thermal,processor,x86_pkg_temp_thermal
hid                   102264  4 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
i2c_core               46012  8 drm,i915,i2c_hid,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,v4l2_common,nouveau,videodev
```

Comment: The realtek card is ethernet; the wifi is Atheros.  Do you have the right atheros drivers loaded?

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried, what doesn't work, what errors....

Comment: yes, I've install the atheros package, but not work

There no errors! Just not work the wireless, just in the cable!

Comment: please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: The right module `ath10k_pci` run `modprobe ath10k_pci`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [firmware-atheros](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/firmware-atheros) from **backport**:

> This package contains the binary firmware for USB wireless network and Bluetooth cards supported by the ar5523, ath3k, ath6kl_sdio, ath6kl_usb, ath9k_htc or **ath10k** drivers.

Edit your `sources.list` :

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

save and install the needed package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-atheros
modprobe ath10k_pci
```

**Edit**

Using the regular repo of the stable version, the `ath10k` isn't included in the `firmware-atheros` package :

> This package contains the binary firmware for USB wireless network and Bluetooth cards supported by the ar5523, ar9170, ath3k, ath6kl_sdio, ath6kl_usb or ath9k_htc drivers

Download **backports** then compile `ath10k`:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.2.6/backports-4.2.6-1.tar.xz
unxz backports-4.2.6-1.tar.xz
tar xvf backports-4.2.6-1.tar.gz
cd  backports-4.2.6-1
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

**edit**

Your Network card is : [QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/168c)

Run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA6174 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot then run `modprobe ath10k_pci`

Comment: I add the result, in my post

Comment: What that i need to do ?

Comment: Install `firmware-atheros` following the first part of my answer .

Comment: I do this and post the answer in the topic

Comment: @Rod i edit my answer.

Comment: Not working!

I try iwconfig , to see wireless connections, and the result is command not found

Comment: no wireless extensions to eth0 and lo

Comment: Rremove `firmware-atheros`  recompile it then run `modprobe ath10k`

Comment: modprobe ath10kmodprobe: FATAL: Module ath10k not found.

Comment: i update the answer with the latest backports release

Comment: Nothing changed... :(
This notebook was with ubuntu and wifi was normally, when I install debian 8.5 , it's broken

Comment: Maybe can be kernel ?
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=126169

Comment: When i shutoff my pc, its happen
https://postimg.org/image/6ee4391h3/

Comment: login as root , run `startx` the right command is `modprobe ath10k_pci`

Comment: I run the command modprobe ath10k_pci , reboot and nothing happens, 
Not errors

Comment: Run `iwconfig` what is the output?

Comment: no wireless extensions.
I posted the result of lsmode command